# Measurement in Quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, measurements, hamiltonian, approximations

I have got a quantum conservative system whose Hamiltonian is $H$. I consider an selfandjoint operator $O$ whose eigenvalues and eigenvectors are: $$O|\psi _{n}\rangle = \lambda _{n}|\psi _{n}\rangle$$

At initial time, the system is at the state $|\psi_{i}\rangle$. At time $t=  \delta t$, I measure with the operator $O$. 
The approximation of the measured state to second order in $\delta t$ is
 $$|\psi(\delta t)\rangle=U(\delta t, 0)|\psi(0)\rangle \;,$$
 with
 $$U(\delta t, 0) = e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}\delta t H} \approx 1 - \frac{i}{\hbar}\delta t H - \frac{1}{2}\left ( \frac{1}{\hbar^2}(\delta t)^2 H^2 \right ) \;;$$
the probability of obtaining $ \lambda _{i}$ in the second order on $\delta t$ is

$$P(\lambda_{i}) \approx 1-\left ( \frac{\delta t}{\hbar}\Delta H_{\psi_{i}} \right )^2 \;,$$ 
where I denote
$$\Bigl(\Delta H_{\psi_{i}}\Bigr)^2= \langle\psi_{i}|H^2|\psi_{i}\rangle-\langle\psi_{i}|H|\psi_{i}\rangle^2$$

**Question.** In what regime the quadratic approximation on delta $\delta t$ is good?

Comment: Looks like a [quantum Zeno effect](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/47252/simple-explanation-of-quantum-zeno-effect) scenario, so t must be short compared to the Zeno time.

Comment: What is the Zeno time?

Comment: It's defined in Dima's answer to the question I linked - basically it's your $\Delta H_{\psi_i}$.  You would probably need $\hbar$ to get the units right to compare it with $\delta t$