# Gentle introduction to the Formalism of Quantum Zeno Effect

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations

I found some potential good sources for Quantum Zeno

[Simple explanation of Quantum Zeno Effect](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/47252/)

https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0307044

Since they are internet sources, I am not sure how formal they are. I am looking for a book or note on the gentle introduction to the Formalism of Quantum Zeno Effect. Could you please help me with it?

I know some quantum mechanics and a lot of quantum chemistry.

Comment: My first, introductory, quantum course was (partially) from Griffiths introduction to quantum mechanics. We went through the whole book and, I recall a section introducing the quantum Zeno effect. They did a nice series expansion of the decay probability fir a state transition and showed for measurements very close together you can increase (or possibly decrease) the lifetime of a state. Very simple introductory explanation.